# refer to components that created by loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to create a components by following this steps:

- I have a list of items.
- I want to loop in this list and create a component like `InputNumber`.
- Add `EventCallback` to the generic created `InputNumber` that accept `ref` of this `Inputtext` because I want to use this `ref` to set the focus on this `InputNumber`.
- I have also `onblure` method that execute some code for me, and I am using the `onfocus` to return focus to the input after execute this code by `onblure`

**My question** 
 How can I get this `ref` and send it as parameter of `EventCallback`?
 The problem here that this components have been generated by loop, so I don't want to create by hand hundred variables to represent `ref's`. 
My concept code like this:

```
@code{
  private void OnFocus(MyInputNumber<double?> obj)
  {
     if (obj is not null)
     {
       obj!.Element.Value.FocusAsync();
     }
  }
}
@foreach(var MyItem in MyList)
{
  <EditForm Model="MyItem">
    //Some components ..
    <label>
        Test
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="MyItem.MyVal"
         @onfocus="@((InputNumber<double?> obj @*wrong*@) =>  
    OnFocus(obj))"
    @onblur=@(() => OnblureHandler(context))
    </label>
 </EditForm>
}
```

If you see up the parameter `InputNumber<double?> obj`, this way is wrong, usually I use `@ref=SomeVariable` but becasue I created in generic way, I can not do that.

## Note:

I don't to adjust my list to be `dictionary<MYItemType,InputNumber<double?>>`, or create a new class that has `InputNumber<double?>` as property. I am searching for different way, like go from `editcontext`  to any input has been modified and reset focus on it, I don't know if that possible !

Comment: What are you trying to focus when `InputNumber` is focused?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos, Thanks for review the question, actually I have another method `Onblure` works with `OnFocus`  and I want to return focusing again to the input!

Comment: Break the contents of the loop into a separate component. It will greatly simplify the logic. Get more SOLID ;)

Comment: Is the intent here to have `onblur` on the element run some code and then set the focus back to the element if the conditions in the code aren't met? (Or something similar!)  If so, one solution is to have lightly modified versions of the input controls with this built in.  If so, I'll do you an answer to show you how.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, This will be great to know other solution, please add your answer for me and for other people.

Comment: @Nb777 - See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `InputNumber<double?> InputNumberRef { get; set; }` property to your model class. Then is the foreach loop bind it to the component reference `@ref="MyItem.InputNumberRef"` then you can pass it in your callback method `@onblur="() => HandleBlur(MyItem.InputNumberRef)"`.

Here is the demo code that I used. The following code after input `onblur` event it waits 2 seconds and returns the focus to the input.

```
@page "/"

@foreach (var item in _items)
{
    <EditForm Model="@item">
        <InputNumber class="form-control" @ref="@item.InputNumberRef" @bind-Value="@item.Value" @onblur="() => HandleBlur(item.InputNumberRef)" />
    </EditForm>
}

@code {

    private List<Item> _items = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item { Value = 10 },
        new Item { Value = 30 },
        new Item { Value = 20 },
    };

    private async Task HandleBlur(InputNumber<int> inputNumberRef)
    {
        if (inputNumberRef.Element.HasValue)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            await inputNumberRef.Element.Value.FocusAsync();
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public InputNumber<int> InputNumberRef { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Credits to user [@enet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152891/enet) for suggesting this solution in a different question on stackoverflow.**

Comment: Thanks again for your soliton, did you see my `Note` about not using `dictionary<MYItemType,InputNumber<double?>>` . Acutely your solution has the same concept, I don't want to create a new class or adjust `MyList `, I am searching for different way, like go from `editcontext ` to any input has been modified and reset focus on it, I don't know if that possible

Comment: I didn't say to create a new class. Add this property to the existing class that `MyList` is using.

Comment: I got what you mean, but actually I am searching for another solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way to access the component references. You have to either create a Dictionary to store them or store them inside the model class itself.

Comment: That could be, I will keep the question for others and for new answers :), thanks again for help.

Comment: You could also add the property to an abstract class and make your models that need it derive from it. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is that you apply some form of complex validation on the content of the input before the user is allowed to leave it, i.e if the handler attached to `onBlur` fails validation then you want to return focus to the input, then this is how to do that without resorting to dictionaries, ...

I've defined a custom `InputText` component to demonstrate the principles.  You'll need to apply the same principles to any other `InputBase` component where you want to apply the functionality. The key is defining a delegate `Func` (which returns a `bool`) as a parameter which is called when the user tries to leave the control.  As everything is contained within the component (a bit of SOLID as pointed out by @BrianParker), we can call the inbuilt `Element` property to return focus to the component.

```cs
@inherits InputText

<input @ref="Element"
       @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
       class="@CssClass"
       value="@CurrentValue"
       @oninput="OnInput"
       @onblur="OnBlur" />

@if (validationMessage != string.Empty)
{
    <div class="validation-message">
        @validationMessage
    </div>
}

@code {
    private string validationMessage = string.Empty;

    [Parameter] public Func<string?, Task<bool>>? BlurValidation { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string ValidationFailMessage { get; set; } = "Failed Validation";

    private void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
        => this.CurrentValueAsString = e.Value?.ToString() ?? null;

    private async Task OnBlur(FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        validationMessage = string.Empty;
        if (Element is not null && BlurValidation is not null && !await this.BlurValidation.Invoke(this.CurrentValue))
        {
            await Element.Value.FocusAsync();
            validationMessage = ValidationFailMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

And a demo page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@foreach(var item in model)
{
    <EditForm Model=item>
        <MyInputText class="form-text" @bind-Value=item.MyCountry BlurValidation=CheckBlur />
    </EditForm>
}

@code {
    private List<MyData> model = new List<MyData>() { new MyData { MyCountry = "UK" }, new MyData { MyCountry = "Australia" } };

    private async Task<bool> CheckBlur(string value)
        {
            // Emulate some async behaviour to do whatever checking is required
            await Task.Delay(100);
            // simple test here to demonstrate - I know you could use nornal validation to do this!
            return value.Length > 5;
        }

    public class MyData
    {
        public string? MyCountry { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure I'm happy with the UX using this design, but it's your code.

Comment: Not sure why you use the Func delegate here, as you benefits nothing from it. On the contrary, this results in additional rendering of both MyInputText and its parent. You can simply check the length of `CurrentValue` in the `OnBlur`method instead. The use of the Func delegate has got nothing to do with "simple test here to demonstrate - I know you could use nornal validation to do this!" You can still demonstrate your validation without using  the Func delegate.

Comment: Incidentally, knowing that you did it for demonstration
purpose only, using data annotations validation is much much better in many respect. The solution to sub-class `InputText` to set the focus is excellent...I've already suggested it in this thread, and then deleted it.

Comment: And yes I saw your initial answer and was going to refer to it in my answer before you deleted it.  I did see that you find out about the inbuilt `Element` in the component.

Comment: @enet - I have no idea what the Op is doing in OnblureHandler(context), so I just used the string length test as something to emulate whatever OnblureHandler does. See the comments in the code "// simple test here to demonstrate - I know you could use nornal validation to do this!" I implementedthe Func delegate so you can doing anything in `OnblureHandler`. Yes you get some "collateral" rendering, but that's a product of using a sledgehammer (ComponentBase) to crack a nut!  And yes, using Validation may actually be the right solution, but who knows what `OnblureHandler` does>.